# Как побайтово считать файл GIF?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как побайтово считать файл GIF. Язык C++

Comment: точно также, как и любой другой бинарный файл.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду считать байты, или хотите увидеть структуру gif или исходники декомпрессора gif?

Answer (score 5):

Поскольку вопрос имеет тэг `C++`, то предложу решение в стиле `C++`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::ifstream input_stream("input.gif", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input_stream)),
                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

*После завершения, `buffer` будет содержать ваш файл `input.gif`.*